# Ruby on rails - The Arabic character is not displayed on mySql in localhost

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding

Im writing a website with ruby on rails. My project is running on both MC2 and localhost (same source, same database connect)
The problem is, when inserting data with my source in localhost, everything fine, arabic characters is correctly inserted to database and displayed on web fine.
But when inserting data with my source in Amz MC2 server, the Arabic character was changed to some weird words. (like 'Ø¶ Ø¶ Ø¶' ...)

This is the variables and how did i insert them:

```
 levelreason = params[:gamestate_level_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  pointsreason = params[:gamestate_points_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  goldreason = params[:gamestate_gold_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  waterreason = params[:gamestate_water_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  oilreason = params[:gamestate_oil_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  pearlsreason = params[:gamestate_pearls_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  diwanlevelreason = params[:gamestate_diwanlevel_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  daggerreason = params[:gamestate_dagger_reason].force_encoding("UTF-8")




 str_querygs = "insert into update_GameState set userId = '#{params[:userId]}', action = 'update gamestate', userChange = '#{session[:user]['username']}'"
      if (params[:gamestate_level] != "" && params[:gamestate_level_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromLevel = #{fromlevel}, ToLevel = #{tolevel}, LevelChangeReason = '#{levelreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_trophies] != "" && params[:gamestate_dagger_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromDagger = #{fromdagger}, ToDagger = #{todagger}, DaggerChangeReason = '#{daggerreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_email] != "" && !fromemail.eql?(toemail))
        str_querygs += ", FromEmail = '#{fromemail}', ToEmail = '#{toemail}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_exper] != "" && params[:gamestate_points_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromExPoint = #{fromexpoint}, ToExPoint = #{toexpoint}, ExPointChangeReason = '#{pointsreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_gold] != "" && params[:gamestate_gold_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromGold = #{fromgold}, ToGold = #{togold}, GoldChangeReason = '#{goldreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_water] != "" && params[:gamestate_water_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromWater = #{fromwater}, ToWater = #{towater}, WaterChangeReason = '#{waterreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_darkwater] != "" && params[:gamestate_oil_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromOil = #{fromoil}, ToOil = #{tooil}, OilChangeReason = '#{oilreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_gems] != "" && params[:gamestate_pearls_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromPearls = #{frompearls}, ToPearls = #{topearls}, PearlsChangeReason = '#{pearlsreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_townhall] != "" && params[:gamestate_diwanlevel_reason] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromDiwanLevel = #{fromdiwanlevel}, ToDiwanLevel = #{todiwanlevel}, DiwanLevelChangeReason = '#{diwanlevelreason}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_isFake] != "")
        str_querygs += ", isFake= '#{params[:gamestate_isFake]}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_facebookId] != "")
        str_querygs += ", FromFacebookId = '#{fromfacebookid}', ToFacebookId = '#{tofacebookid}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_username] != "" && !fromname.eql?(toname))
        str_querygs += ", FromName = '#{fromname}', ToName = '#{toname}'"
      end
      if (params[:gamestate_locale] != "" && !fromlocal.eql?(tolocal))
        str_querygs += ", FromLocal = '#{fromlocal}', ToLocal = '#{tolocal}'"
      end
      @db.query(str_querygs)
```

thank you!

Comment: Make sure your MySQL instance uses the correct character set: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

Comment: hi @UriAgassi, yeah my MySQL used correct character set. So on the local (using same sql connector with mc2), the correct arabic character was inserted on the database. I was upgraded the ruby version (from 1.9.3) on mc2 to 2.1.2 as the same with my mac mini. But nothing better...